# Ubuntu 20.04 no sound issue

Tags: sound, 20.04, lenovo

I've upgraded my Ubuntu to 20.04 for a while now, and today suddenly when I was in the middle of the meeting there is no sound coming out. I tried everything and nothing works with me. When I plug my headphones the sound is working fine. I have a dual boot with Windows 10 and the sound works fine on it. My laptop is a Lenovo legion y730.

There are some output samples of what I tried:

```
$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
3e:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron/Crucial Technology P1 NVMe PCIe SSD (rev 03)
3f:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

```
$ sudo lspci -v 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 62000000-630fffff [size=17M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000050000000-0000000061ffffff [size=288M]
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
    Capabilities: [d94] Secondary PCI Express
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 158
    Memory at 6022000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 6023100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 6023119000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10) Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 6023118000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at 63300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at 6023110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at 6023117000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 602310c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Null
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 4010000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 4010001000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 143
    Memory at 6023114000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at 63310000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at 63314000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5088 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Memory at 63313000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=3d, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00008fff [size=12K]
    Memory behind bridge: 64000000-7a0fffff [size=353M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006000000000-0000006021ffffff [size=544M]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Null
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3e, subordinate=3e, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: 63200000-632fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3f, subordinate=3f, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 63100000-631fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    Memory at 4010002000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3802
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 159
    Memory at 6023108000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6023000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at 6023112000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 62000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 50000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at 60000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [disabled] [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 63080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 63000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
3e:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron/Crucial Technology P1 NVMe PCIe SSD (rev 03) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Micron/Crucial Technology P1 NVMe PCIe SSD
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 63200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [158] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
3f:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at 63104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 63100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C multimedia
 *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:63000000-63003fff
  *-usb:3
       description: Video
       product: Integrated Camera
       vendor: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
       physical id: 7
       bus info: usb@1:7
       version: 0.27
       serial: 0001
       capabilities: usb-2.01
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:159 memory:6023108000-602310bfff memory:6023000000-60230fffff
```

```
$ uname -a
 Linux mosama 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have also tried purging alsa-base and pulseaudio and reinstalling it again.

The speakers appear working as in the screenshot but I can't hear anything.

[image: sound settings]

Answer (score 0):

Go to alsamixer window on terminal and unmute all the options, as well as, changing the volume of them all. I also had a similar problem a while back

Comment: All options are unmuted and still no sound, do you have any idea why still not working?

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar problems when updated to 20.04 and reported the bug.
Finally this ppa fixed my problem.
[https://launchpad.net/~kaihengfeng/+archive/ubuntu/fix-lp1869819](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekaihengfeng/+archive/ubuntu/fix-lp1869819)